# Visual studio 2017 problem with namespaces in F#

Tags: visual-studio, f#

I wrote this in HelperFunctions.fs:

```
namespace Tutorial1.HelperFunctions

module Factorials = 

    let rec fact n = 
        match n with
            | 0 -> 1
            | 1 -> 1
            | _ -> n * fact (n - 1)
```

And then this in Tutorial.fsx:

```
#load "HelperFunctions.fs"
open Tutorial1.HelperFunctions

module start = 
    let x = Factorials.fact 5
    printfn "%d" x
```

Code compiles and returns 120 as expected BUT: VS throws FS0039 error: Factorials and Tutorial1 namespace, type or module not defined... Tried many other combinations of open, module etc but then codes does not even compile. What is the problem I am not seeing here?

Comment: Tried unsuccessfully to reproduce your problem. Used VS 2017 (15.8.5) and F# Interactive 10.2.3 for F# 4.5, .NET Standard 2.0 library named Tutorial1, with HelperFunctions.fs and Tutorial.fsx. Copied your code samples exactly, and it built fine and ran in F# Interactive successfully without the FS0039 error. Do you see the error in F# Interactive output?

Comment: I opened a  working project that compiled just fine (some random big code from github), added one file to the project (did not edit anything else), tried compiling it, and suddenly it got error in the main file, FS0222? this is ridicolous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, apparently the order of files in the vstudio matters, even if you include the file with #load. I had to shift the files upwards and it worked